# Pandas None to NaN after concat: bug or intentional behavior?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an initial DataFrame like this:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({"value":(None,)})
```

If I use `pd.concat` on it, the resulting DataFrame has the `None` converted to a `NaN`:

```
In [14]: pd.concat([d], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
Out[14]:
  value
0   NaN
```

This does not happen if I have a DataFrame with mixed text/`None`:

```
In [15]: d2 = pd.DataFrame({"value":("a", None)})

In [16]: pd.concat([d2], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
Out[16]:
  value
0     a
1  None
```

I'm having trouble understanding this behavior. Is this a bug, or is there some special reasoning behind it?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug. Here's workaround:

```
import numpy as np
...
d2 = d2.apply(lambda v: v if v is not None else np.nan)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems It's a bug in older version of pandas

Which version of pandas you are using?

I'm using pandas 0.20.3 and the dataframe value None remains same and not converted to NaN when I ran your code.

Try upgrading your pandas version and check.

Found a [document](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/10571) related to your question.